# python - Raw load as an answer

Tags: python, sockets, scapy, raw-data

Im trying to send an NTP query using scapy and sockets, but when i receive date i get it in a raw form.

```
from scapy.all import*
from scapy.all import*
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
addr=("192.114.62.250",123)
ntp=NTP()
s.sendto(str(ntp),addr)
data,ip=s.recvfrom(1024)
```

the answer should be in data but all i get is

> '\x1c\x02\n\xeb\x00\x00\x01b\x00\x00\r\x8c\xc0s\xd12\xdcH\xa5\xda}-\x1b/\xdcH\xa9T\x95\x81\x08\x00\xdcH\xa9_\xd2\xc2n\xe1\xdcH\xa9_\xd2\xc6\xca\x1c'

and what i want is :

```
Peer Clock Stratum: secondary reference (2)
Peer Polling Interval: 10 (1024 sec)
Peer Clock Precision: 0.000000 sec
Root Delay:    0.0054 sec
Root Dispersion:    0.0529 sec
Reference ID: 192.115.209.50
Reference Timestamp: Feb 10, 2017 20:49:30.488969000 UTC
Origin Timestamp: Feb 10, 2017 21:04:20.584000000 UTC
Receive Timestamp: Feb 10, 2017 21:04:31.823279000 UTC
Transmit Timestamp: Feb 10, 2017 21:04:31.823345000 UTC
```

Comment: Add a space before the * in the import statement, and post debug messages of all your vars. Also, try decoding the data using the builtin decode function

Comment: i tried decoding it, but it just doesnt work.. cant understand why.

Comment: Post the debugging of all vars so we can help.

Comment: there is only ip which is a tuple that has the IP and port, and data is the answer from the NTP query that i have sent, again i receive it a raw form and i want it as i showed above

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
data = data.replace("\\", "\\\\")
data.decode('string-escape')
print data
```

Answer (score -1):

Turns out you can just make turn data into an NTP

```
data= NTP(data)
```

and I got what i wanted.